# How to define disturbed/clipped contours elevation for Volume Polygon?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, contour, tin, clip, volume

I want to calculate surface volume for different layer on TIN surface. 
I am working on an area in Norway which is 1 km * 1 km. The aim is to calculate surface volume of different imaginary elevation.

Because it is a clipped area of a big Island,some contours have been clipped as well ! Now the problem is those areas that have been clipped considering as zero or plane surface, although they are almost high hills and have around 140 m height !

Is there any way to prevent this error or fix the disturbed contours??

I attached the picture for become more clear!
[image]